# Prototype of Object is proto to String

Tags: javascript

I write the following code snippet:

```
Object.prototype.getAllKeyValuePair=function(){
    var str="";
    for(var p in this){
        str=str+"{"+p+", "+this[p]+"}";
    }
    return str;
}
alert(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(String.prototype.getAllKeyValuePair));
```

I excepted that `String.prototype.getAllKeyValuePair` is `undefined` because I don't set a `String` prototype explicitly. Please explain why when wy define an Object prototype it will define a String prototype automatically?

Comment: In JavaScript, (almost) *everything* extends `Object`.

Comment: String.prototype is an object, why wouldn't it inherit from Object.prototype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The String.prototype object "inherits" from the Object.prototype object.

In Firefox, Chrome or Safari, try this:

```
alert(String.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype)
```

That should alert `true`.

Check out [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) over at MDN.

Answer (score 1):

This is because pretty much every type in javascript inherits from object, and as you are extending the object type via prototype, each object that inherits from it will also have access to the function you have defined.